# Connecting VPN in Circleci WIndows Instance

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, circleci

I am facing this error while connecting to VPN in circleci. Has anyone encountered this ?
Context: I wanted to deploy files to AWS Windows EC2 instance  and I am doing that using ssh in cirleci. In my EC2 instance, I have added inbound rule in port 22 of SSH to only allow connections from VPN connected connection only.
[image]

Edit:
Here is my config file:

```
  build-deploy:
    working_directory: ~/repo
    executor:
      name: windows/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          paths:
            - node_modules
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: npm run build
      - run:
            name: Connect to VPN
            command: .\.circleci\connectVPN.ps1
      - run:
          name: Install POSH-SSH
          command: .\.circleci\install_posh_ssh.ps1
      - run:
          name: Update Host
          command: .\.circleci\set_known_hosts.ps1
      - run:
          name: Deploy App into EC2
          command: .\.circleci\ssh_deploy.ps1
```

`connectVPN.ps1`

```
$VPN_NAME = $env:VPN_NAME
$VPN_ADDRESS = $env:VPN_ADDRESS
$VPN_USERNAME = $env:VPN_USERNAME
$VPN_PASSWORD = $env:VPN_PASSWORD

# If VPN with this name is present, then remove it
if ([bool] (Get-VpnConnection -Name "$VPN_NAME")) {
  # Remove it
  Remove-VpnConnection -Name "$VPN_NAME" -Force
}

# Adds the new VPN Connection
Add-VpnConnection -Name "$VPN_NAME" -ServerAddress "$VPN_ADDRESS" -TunnelType Pptp -EncryptionLevel NoEncryption -AuthenticationMethod Pap -RememberCredential -PassThru
# Connect the VPN configuration
$code = (Start-Process rasdial -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "$VPN_NAME $VPN_USERNAME $VPN_PASSWORD" -PassThru -Verbose -Wait).ExitCode

if ("$code" -eq "0") {
  Write-Host "Create and connect to VPN server success" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
} else {
  # Error codes: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/824864/list-of-error-codes-for-dial-up-connections-or-vpn-connections
  if ("$code" -eq "691") {
    Write-Host "Create and connect to VPN server failed with wrong username or password" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
  } else {
      Write-Host "Create and connect to VPN server failed with error code: $($code)" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
      throw "$code"
  }
}
```

Comment: What VPN solution are you using? Could you share your CircleCI config, in particular the part where you attempt to establish the VPN connection?

Comment: I have made changes above. Please, take a look.

Comment: Instead of running the `.circleci\connectVPN.ps1` script directly, could you try creating a service from it?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't understand, What do you mean by creating a service ? Can you please share any example ?

Comment: See [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7.2).